# LINQ GroupBy string PagePath

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of entries `List<StatisticsData>`

```
 public class StatisticsData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }   
    public string PagePath { get; set; }    
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Sample values:

```
    94F0F2FF-D251-46AA-8AF4-E1CE14A70DFF | osahori.com.pr | 2020-02-18 
    1697C57B-BD10-43A2-B0F8-EDDFD289AB9B | osahori.com.pr/clientes | 2020-02-18 
    E91C049A-2F63-4B2E-87BD-B41284332614 | osahori.com.pr/faco-seu-orcamento | 2020-02-18 
    E91C049A-2F63-4B2E-87BD-B41284332614 | tc.onsiege.com/ | 2020-02-18 
    BF596A54-C9FF-4FE4-8881-3C1BBCA6C3A6 | tc.onsiege.com/home | 2020-02-18
    5D32AF13-B7F9-40BB-927C-C07C5AC994FF | www.ubertaxi.com.br | 2020-02-18 
    17B5925F-8EFD-4DE1-BC56-4CB1241D0EF1 | www.ubertaxi.com.br/clients | 2020-02-18
    ...
```

In result I need groups for the same context of `PagePath`, e.g:

First group:

```
    94F0F2FF-D251-46AA-8AF4-E1CE14A70DFF | osahori.com.pr | 2020-02-18 
    1697C57B-BD10-43A2-B0F8-EDDFD289AB9B | osahori.com.pr/clientes | 2020-02-18 
    E91C049A-2F63-4B2E-87BD-B41284332614 | osahori.com.pr/faco-seu-orcamento | 2020-02-18
```

Second group:

```
   E91C049A-2F63-4B2E-87BD-B41284332614 | tc.onsiege.com/ | 2020-02-18 
   BF596A54-C9FF-4FE4-8881-3C1BBCA6C3A6 | tc.onsiege.com/home | 2020-02-18
```

Third:

```
    5D32AF13-B7F9-40BB-927C-C07C5AC994FF | www.ubertaxi.com.br | 2020-02-18 
    17B5925F-8EFD-4DE1-BC56-4CB1241D0EF1 | www.ubertaxi.com.br/clients | 2020-02-18
```

Etc.

Is it possible to do with LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t5THVW)

You can `GroupBy` the exact path only, like `osahori.com.pr, tc.onsiege.com` by using `Subtring` like below.

**Note that:** Check the case `PagePath` has no `"/"`.

```
    var result = list.GroupBy(p => 
                {
                    var indexOf = p.PagePath.IndexOf('/');
                    return indexOf > 0 ? p.PagePath.Substring(0, indexOf) : p.PagePath;
                });

    foreach(var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Group: " + item.Key);
        foreach(var item2 in item.ToList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item2.Id + "|" + item2.PagePath + "|" + item2.Date);
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
Group: osahori.com.pr
94F0F2FF-D251-46AA-8AF4-E1CE14A70DFF|osahori.com.pr|2/18/2020 12:00:00 AM
1697C57B-BD10-43A2-B0F8-EDDFD289AB9B|osahori.com.pr/clientes|1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
E91C049A-2F63-4B2E-87BD-B41284332614|osahori.com.pr/faco-seu-orcamento|1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
Group: tc.onsiege.com
E91C049A-2F63-4B2E-87BD-B41284332614|tc.onsiege.com/|2/18/2020 12:00:00 AM
BF596A54-C9FF-4FE4-8881-3C1BBCA6C3A6|tc.onsiege.com/home|2/18/2020 12:00:00 AM
Group: www.ubertaxi.com.br
5D32AF13-B7F9-40BB-927C-C07C5AC994FF|www.ubertaxi.com.br|2/18/2020 12:00:00 AM
17B5925F-8EFD-4DE1-BC56-4CB1241D0EF1|www.ubertaxi.com.br/clients|1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Good work with examples, thank you. What if I want to make another groups with content of 2+ prev groups? How I can configure to have x prev groups in new?

Comment: Could you give me your expected result?

Comment: You can add `.Take(2);`. For example `var result = list.GroupBy(p => 
          {
           var indexOf = p.PagePath.IndexOf('/');
           return indexOf > 0 ? p.PagePath.Substring(0, indexOf) : p.PagePath;
          }).Take(2);` https://dotnetfiddle.net/fesN7A

Comment: It doesn't work, because it cuts the next entries. I need  to have new groups which contain data from X prev groups. 1st new group - 2 prev groups, 2nd - next 2 prev groups.

Comment: Please check your expected result then send me it. Otherwise, you can create new question to keep this question as simple as possible (Help the reader in the future)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208479/discussion-between-hoozr-and-phong).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, quite easily:

```
var grouped = listStatisticsData
  .GroupBy(sd => sd.PagePath.Substring(0, sd.PagePath.IndexOf('/')));
```

It will group by part of `PagePath` until first occurence of `/`. Keys will be automatically stored as result of `sd.PagePath.IndexOf('/')`

Comment: The problem is `PagePath` has no `"/"`. So you should check that case as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60389567/9071943

Answer (score 1):

Well, given a `PagePath` we should `GroupBy` either by entire `PagePath` if it doesn't contain `/` (e.g. `osahori.com.pr`) or by
the prefix before *first* `/` (say, `osahori.com.pr` for `osahori.com.pr/clientes`):

```
 var result = listStatisticsData
   .GroupBy(item => {
      int p = item.PagePath.IndexOf('/');

      return p < 0 ? item.PagePath : item.PagePath.Substring(0, p);  
    })
```

Comment: Good suggestion for prefixes and / mark existence. Thank you!